# running celery as daemon using supervisor is not working

Tags: django, celery, supervisord, celery-task

I have a django app in which it has a celery functionality, so i can able to run the celery sucessfully like below

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

but as a known fact that we need to run it as a daemon and so i have written the below `celery.conf` file inside `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/` folder

```
; ==================================
;  celery worker supervisor example
; ==================================

[program:celery]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/root/Envs/proj/bin/celery -A app.tasks worker --loglevel=info

user=root
environment=C_FORCE_ROOT="yes"
environment=HOME="/root",USER="root"
directory=/root/apps/proj/structure
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```

but when i tried to update the supervisor like `supervisorctl reread` and `supervisorctl update` i was getting the message from `supervisorctl status`

```
celery                           FATAL      Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

So i went to `worker.log` file and seen the error message as below

```
Running a worker with superuser privileges when the
worker accepts messages serialized with pickle is a very bad idea!

If you really want to continue then you have to set the C_FORCE_ROOT
environment variable (but please think about this before you do).

User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0
```

So why it was complaining about  `C_FORCE_ROOT` even though we had set it as environment variable inside supervisor conf file ? what am i doing wrong in the above conf file ?

Comment: Don't run as root — it's shouldn't be necessary. (Are you using this with Django — run as the same user as there.)

Comment: yeah ok when i removed the line `environment=HOME="/root",USER="root"` it was working fine

Comment: I was having this problem with AWS Elasticbeanstalk, using user=ec2-user fixed it for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem,so I added

```
environment=C_FORCE_ROOT="yes"
```

in my program config,but It didn't work
so I used

```
environment=C_FORCE_ROOT="true"
```

it's working

Comment: tried this export C_FORCE_ROOT='true'. Also added this to bashrc. Even then it is not working

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to run celery with a non superuser account, Please remove following lines from your config:

```
user=root
environment=C_FORCE_ROOT="yes"
environment=HOME="/root",USER="root"
```

And the add these lines to your config, I assume that you use `django` as a non superuser and `developers` as the user group:

```
user=django
group=developers
```

> Note that subprocesses will inherit the environment variables of the
>   shell used to start supervisord except for the ones overridden here
>   and within the program’s environment option. See [supervisord documents](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment).

So Please note that when you change environment variables via `supervisor` config files, **Changes won't apply** by running `supervisorctl reread` and `supervisorctl reload` . You should run supervisor from the very start by following command:

```
supervisord -c /path/to/config/file.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

From [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376684/how-to-run-celery-workers-by-superuser#37376769) on stackoverflow. I managed to add the following settings and it worked for me.

```
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json'],
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json',
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json',
)
```